# Unable to use Apple's Mail.app as Exchange 2010 client!

Tags: email, mac-osx, exchange-2010, outlook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to use Mac for Exchange 2010 client!](https://serverfault.com/questions/263998/unable-to-use-mac-for-exchange-2010-client)

I have this strange problem. Recently I have switched to Mac, we use Exchange 2010 for mail and calenders, some how I'm unable to sync/connect my exchange account with either Mail.app or Outlook 2011. But, everything works on Outlook 2010. I have details of CAS server. Still unable to connect my mac with Exchange?

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? Is this an issue inside the network or from the outside?

Comment: I just get message telling that unable to connect Client Access server check network connection. It is puzzling that everything work on windows!

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more detail about the error you are seeing. It could be that you are not using SSL. Most Exchange 2010 servers require SSL now. Also, is it possible you are using hosted exchange?